# Nx build does not include scss files

Tags: angular, sass, build

I have an Angular library in my Nx workspace, which I want to build using the `nx build` command.
However, after building the library, the build directory does not contain any (s)css file.

At this point, I am not sure, how to correctly setup the `package.json`, `tsconfig.lib.json` and the `project.json`.

Until now I tried the following configurations in the `project.json`, `package.json` and `tsconfig.lib.json`, which is a combination of several approaches I found in other posts.

**project.json**

```
"name": "build-lib",
    "$schema": "../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",  

    "projectType": "library",  
    "sourceRoot": "libs/build-lib/src",  
    "targets": {  
        "build": {  
            "executor": "@nrwl/angular:ng-packagr-lite",  
            "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"],  
            "options": {  
                "project": "libs/build-lib/ng-package.json"  
            },  
            "style": {  
                "includePaths": ["src"]  
            },  
            "configurations": {  
                "production": {  
                    "tsConfig": "libs/build-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"  
                },  
                "development": {  
                    "tsConfig": "libs/build-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"  
                }  
            },  
            "defaultConfiguration": "production",  
            "assets": [  
                {  
                    "glob": "**/*",  
                    "input": "libs/build-lib/src",  
                    "output": "/",  
                    "styles": ["src/index.scss"]  
                }  
            ]  
        },  
        "test": {  
            "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",  
            "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],  
            "options": {  
                "jestConfig": "libs/build-lib/jest.config.ts",  
                "passWithNoTests": true  
            },  
            "configurations": {  
                "ci": {  
                    "ci": true,  
                    "codeCoverage": true  
                }  
            }  
        },  
        "lint": {  
            "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",  
            "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],  
            "options": {  
                "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/build-lib/**/*.ts",   "libs/build-lib/**/*.html"]  
            }  
        }  
    },  
    "assets": ["src/index.scss"],  
    "styles": ["src/index.scss"],  
    "tags": []}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "@build-lib",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^15.1.0"  
    },  
    "dependencies": {  
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"  
    },  
    "sideEffects": false,  
    "style": "dist/libs/build-lib/index.scss"  
}
```

**tsconfig.lib.json**

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",  
    "compilerOptions": {  
        "outDir": "../../../../dist/out-tsc",  
        "declaration": true,  
        "declarationMap": true,  
        "inlineSources": true,  
        "types": []  
    },  
  "exclude": ["src/test-setup.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts",   
  "jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],  
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.scss"]   
}
```

Comment: Do you find the solution?